# Writing to NVRAM from U-boot shell mode

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, embedded, u-boot

Hardware device with embedded system. NVRAM is corrupted, and I want replace nvram. Is it possible to update NVRAM from within U-boot shell mode?
U-boot provide option to upgrade firmware, u-boot, uimage and other components: two examples from U-boot code:

```
update_uboot=tftpboot 0x80000100 u-boot.bin && protect off 0x48000000 +${filesize} && erase 0x48000000 +${filesize} && sleep ${sdelay} && cp.b ${fileaddr} 0x48000000 ${filesize} && protect on 0x48000000 +${filesize}

update_uimage=tftpboot 0x80000100 uImage && protect off ${UBFIADDR1} +${filesize} && erase ${UBFIADDR1} +${filesize} && sleep ${sdelay} && cp.b ${fileaddr} ${UBFIADDR1} ${filesize} && protect on ${UBFIADDR1} +${filesize}
```

There is no any directions or tips for NVRAM upgrade in U-boot code. The nvram.bin offset address is specified in u-boot settings, is it possible to replace NVRAM from U-boot shell mode? How to unlock NVRAM for writing from within u-boot shell? I tried write to NVRAM, but it not allows.

Here is U-boot [dump](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=W6mnfUaq) with all commands inside.
Spansion Serial Flash S25FL064A

Comment: Can you also detail what happens when you try to boot?

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with software development/programming, it's probably off-topic for SO.  Not sure where it should go, however.

Comment: [U-boot](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vXNMZNkG) bootloader works normally. I'm trying to find how to access nvram for writing.

Comment: What I am asking is how you know that nvram is corrupted and if you can boot the device to modify nvram from within the firmware.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable because you haven't described the hardware configuration.  *"NVRAM"* is a generic term, and U-Boot typically handles NAND Flash and serial Flash and EEPROM with different commands.  What does the `help` command output?  Those two environment variables for updating the U-Boot and kernel images indicate that whatever storage device is used is **soft-memory-mapped** into address space.  This memory map should be displayed on startup, so you should paste all of the U-Boot startup output into your post.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=usYW0fih) is commands and full u-boot output. I can't access web interface, after I changed some settings via admin gui, so I assume that there's something wrong with nvram and it's likely currupted. I can boot normally, and I can update firmware via u-boot shell. Is there way to access NVRAM from u-boot shell?

Comment: If the processor can electrically speaking write to the memory, and you have the details for the necessary operations, then you can add this capabulity to u-boot if it is not already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You supplied the following U-Boot command output:

```
=> md nvram
00000000: 7b1b1185 77ef4e0f 20082c8c 561a45d0    {...w.N. .,.V.E.
00000010: 699012a1 c36840a9 8f825272 9fd95faf    i....h@...Rr.._.
...
```

That is bogus data for "nvram".
From the **printenv** output, there is no environment variable name "nvram".
The symbol "nvram" appears to be undefined, and seems to default to the value of 0.

Based on the kernel command line and MTD partition map, what you call *"NVRAM"* may not be a memory device, but rather one partition in the Spansion serial Flash chip, i.e.

```
partitions[4] = {.name = nvram, .offset = 0x007b0000,.size = 0x00050000 (320K) }
```

If so, that partition would apparently map to 0x487b0000 through 0x487fffff in U-Boot.

You should be able to inspect that partition's data using the command

```
md 0x487b0000
```

If you want to make a copy of it, you should boot into Linux and use the **dd** command

```
dd if=/dev/mtdblock4 of=save_nvram.img
```

Compare this image file to what you want to write to see if it is actually corrupted.

> Is it possible to update NVRAM from within U-boot shell mode?

Assuming that "NVRAM" is actually the partition at the end of the serial Flash, then yes.
Based on the command syntax of the two update variables, the following U-Boot commands should accomplish the task:

```
tftpboot 0x80001000 new_nvram.img
protect off 0x487b0000 +0x50000
erase 0x487b0000 +0x50000
cp.b 0x80001000 0x487b0000 0x50000
protect on 0x487b0000 +0x50000
```

---

Note:
There's an inconsistency in the information that you provided.
 From the U-Boot **printenv** command, **bootargs** is defined as:

```
root=/dev/mtdblock5 mtdparts=physmap-flash.0:512k(U-Boot)ro,256K(env1),256K(env2),0x40000(script),0x140000(Kernel),0x140000(RootFileSystem),5M@1M(UBFI1),5M(UBFI2) console=ttyS0,115200n8 ethaddr0=${ethaddr}
```

But the kernel log indicates that the actual comand line passed was

```
root=/dev/mtdblock3 mtdparts=spansion:0x20000(U-Boot)ro,0x10000(env1),0x10000(env2),0x2d0000@0x4a0000(fWare-FS),0x50000@0x7B0000(nvram),0x3B0000@0x40000(UBFI1),0x3B0000@0x3F0000(UBFI2) console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

Comment: Thank you for helping to solve this problem. I tried that commands before, and it didn't worked - because I used wrong NVRAM address format: **0x007b0000**, instead of **0x487b0000**. Therefore I got the `Error: end address (0x007fffff) not in flash! Bad address format.` After replacing the NVRAM, the admin interface is up again, so for sure, that was NVRAM problem. Just for info, here is [nvram](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dgyzZAXi) before and after upgrade. 
N.B.: Does it possible copy and download nvram via tftp to computer with U-boot shell commands?

Comment: One note: Yes, there is inconsistency in **bootargs** from the U-Boot printenv command and Kernel log (actual commands). I guess this is due to that firmware was developed and compiled on different hardware. Should I change the **bootargs** in U-boot settings to _actual_ values from the Kernel log? What would be the proper syntax for that?

Comment: *"Does it possible copy and download nvram via tftp to computer with U-boot"* -- No, U-Boot's **tftp** is a one direction transfer from the server to the target. *"Should I change the bootargs"* -- I wasn't sure if that was from the same board or not.  You or whoever maintains the board need to remember that the built-in command line is used and not from U-Boot.  If you want to make them the same then you need to learn the basic U-Boot commands such as **setenv** and **saveenv**.  Use `setenv bootargs root=...` where the "root=..." text is the same as the actual kernel command line.